# How to implement scrolling feature for a zoomed-in timeline in React.js?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scroll

I am working on a React.js application that includes a timeline feature similar to Premiere Pro. The timeline has a zooming functionality that allows users to zoom in and out using two handlers on the left and right side of the timeline. Now, I want to implement a scrolling feature when the timeline is zoomed in, similar to the scrolling behavior in Premiere Pro, see below screenshot of Premiere Pro timeline.
[image]

Screenshot from my app timeline:
[image]

The zooming functionality is already working using the left and right zoom handlers. Now, I need help implementing the scrolling feature. Here's what I want to achieve:

1. When the timeline is zoomed in, users should be able to scroll left and right within the timeline to see different sections of the content.
2. The scrolling should update the visible time range on the timeline, so the user can see different parts of the timeline content as they scroll.
3. I want the scrolling to feel smooth and responsive, similar to the scrolling behavior in video editing applications like Premiere Pro.

I'm not sure how to approach this scrolling feature with React.js. Can someone provide guidance or a code example on how to implement the scrolling behavior for a zoomed-in timeline in a React.js component?